How much does our conscious recognition of time affect our circadian rhythm?
Thought experiment:
All timezones have been deleted, and everyone on Earth switched to an arbitrary Global Time that is the same anywhere on the planet. Bob is an early riser and have always duly slept at 8pm and woke up at 6am. He believes in sleeping and waking up early. His body, of course, is well adjusted to this schedule.
Now, with his local time deleted, under this new Global Time, the previous 8pm becomes 2am. Similarly, 6am becomes 12pm. Suddenly, Bob became a "night owl". But of course, nothing else has changed, and his biological body is still adhering to the exact same schedule.
Will Bob's conscious uncomfort to sleeping this late cause him to sleep earlier?

Welcome. Have you heard of the circadian clock / circadian rhythm? Have you thought about jet lag? Skim through the site by typing these relevant terms and see whether you can refine your question; specifically, this isn't a thought experiment, it happens when traveling overseas, when someone looses sight (experimentally by blindfolding or accidentally due to injury).
